# What is the faster way to count substrings in string using python

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm trying to find a fast algorithm for counting how many times a substring is found in a string using Python. I know there are some builtin functions for doing that but they do no serve my propose. For example, the word **"ana"** appears 2 times in **"banana"** but the string method *count* just returns 1.
The code I have so far is:

```
s = "banana"
sub = "ana"
count = 0
for i in range(4):
    if s.startswith(sub):
        count += 1
```

If some one knows a better way, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

possible this:

```
s = "banana"
sub = "ana"
count = len(s.split(sub))-1
```

Comment: Thank's but it will not work. For example, if instead of "ana" sub has "a" the answer would be incorrect. It would be 4 instead of 3.

Comment: you are right. Edited here